# I have problems with a function to impose monotonicity

Tags: r, restriction

I am new in R. I am trying to impose monotonicity conditions to a translog production function. I am using the function `translogMonoRestr`. I loaded my data, the coeff and the inv of the var cov matrix. I imported this from excel and all good

```
read_excel("rtl2.xlsx")
uCoef <- read_excel("matrixbtl2.xlsx")
uCovInv <- read_excel("matrixinvtl2.xlsx")
```

but when I tried:

```
monoRestr <- translogMonoRestr( xNames, = c( "lx1", "lx2"), rtl2.xlsx , dataLogged = TRUE)
```

I got **Error in testNames %in% allNames : object 'rtl2' not found**.

Then I'll use `solve.QP` but that is another topic.

I hope someone can help me with this error message

Thanks

Comment: Did you create an object when you ran `read.excel("rtl2.xlsx")`? It looks like you just read the file without doing that, so then the results aren't there for `monoRestr` to find.

Comment: right, I had forgotten that... it worked!! thanks ulfelder